# MongoDB smarter use of $or when having many of the same comparisons

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

This works fine - I just wonder if there is a smarter way to do it?

```
db.getCollection("property")
     .find( { $or: [ { unique: "ATL-D406" }, 
                     { unique: "ATL-D407" }, 
                     { unique: "ATL-D411" }, 
                     { unique: "ATL-D412" } ] } )
```

Perhaps something like;

`$or {unique: ["ATL-D406", "ATL-D407", "ATL-D411", "ATL-D412"]}` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$in` operator, which is detailed [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/)

Usage is as below;

```
db.getCollection("property")
      .find( { unique: { $in: [ "ATL-D406", "ATL-D407", "ATL-D411", "ATL-D412" ] } } )
```

Comment: Ahhh I didnt know $in, just tried it out and it works perfectly - thanks a lot @bureaquete :)  --- Say you want to do the same thing in an aggregate, how would you do that?

Comment: Ahh.... I just put a $match: { } around it, and it worked.   Great!!  ok, learned something new today :)